# Is the description changeable after submit to AppStore review

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I'm planning to submit the application to AppStore,
however, I have been not written complete description yet.

So I'm going to submit with brief description.

Is the description changeable after submit to AppStore review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, descriptions are editable anytime, even after Apple approves the binary. The screenshots are also editable.

Answer (score 1):

**No the description isn't changeable, you will need to re-submitt the app for the changes to be made

EDIT- The description **is** in fact changeable, my mistake. Sorry all

Comment: My mistake, i tried it on an app and it must have taken a bit to update. Sorry about that